# Create custom webform when creating node?

Tags: 8, nodes, webforms, paragraphs

I’m trying to find out if it’s possible to create webforms when creating nodes or paragraphs.

I mean instead of choosing a predefined webform, then build it right inside the field.

I figured that there might be a field widget or something that could do this out of the box, but I can’t seem to find anything.

Am I wrong, is this something unique, or is it a commonly used feature that I just can’t seem to find?

Comment: Webforms are complex things with not just fields but a whole range of associated settings. Are you expecting to be able to embed the entire webform config interface in a node edit form?

Comment: No, more like a bunch of fields where I could define which ones to use. EG. one node would have name and email, and another would only have email field.

Comment: I think you'll either have to define all possible combinations and select the one you want or write a custom module that alters a form depending on field settings. It doesn't seem a common enough requirement for an existing contrib to solve.

Comment: OK, thank you for the information.

Comment: If you want some pre-defined fields for different types of webforms you can try webform templates.